# MSI CPU Fan spins then stops and spins again

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu, computer-building, overheating

I have a MSI GS63VR 7RF Stealth pro. A couple days ago, I noticed it the laptop getting hot.

I mostly use the laptop for music producing/video editing. To go into further detail, I run a program called FL Studio, and on FL Studio you use Virtual Instruments "VSTs" . The issue started when I updated one of the VSTs which uses a lot of CPU itself, even before the update.

When I updated this certain VST I noticed the CPU and GPU temps to go up. At first I wasnt sure why the Laptop was getting so hot.

I noticed the CPU fan did one full spin, and it stopped, then it kept repeating. I did some minor research and it started to clean out the fans. They did have some dust built up. The only problem was that I wasn't able to completely take out the mother board to clean the fans all the way right. I only went as far as taking a couple screws and unplugging some things off the mother board. So I got as much dust from in between the propellers.

I spun the GPU fans while I was dusting it off and the fan spun freely, both fans did.
The CPU one in the other hand, was a bit stiff but not to the point where it couldn't spin. In Dragon Center the RPM says 0 for the CPU and in the GPU it works regularly. I also I tried testing the fan out with cooler boost, but it would just do the same thing it always does, while the GPU fans work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any fan showing any signs at all of not spinning freely when gently pushed should be replaced. They're not worth trying to fix.

You can usually get replacement fans for most lappies on eBay etc from China for a couple of $£€ - two or three weeks for delivery; or locally for $£€ 15 or so, so it depends on how much of a rush you're in.

You can usually find the part number on the part itself, even if it's underneath.

Comment: I turned it on to see if it was still had the same issue, now it's spinning by itself, But its like not constant. Then RPM showed once or twice this time, but then it didn't show at all. It just stayed at 0 again. Tried cooler boost once more, but it didn't end up going faster.